# Mover TextBox criado por código

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando mover um TextBox que foi criado via código, para baixo. Segue o código onde crio e adiciono o botão:

```
    private DVJPetControles.TextBox txtHorarioCheckin;

    this.txtHorarioCheckin.TituloLabel = "Horário de Check-in";
    this.txtHorarioCheckin.TxtPrincipalMask = "00:00";
    this.txtHorarioCheckin.TxtPrincipalTextAlign = 
    HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    this.txtHorarioCheckin.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(189, 45);
    this.txtHorarioCheckin.TabIndex = 
    chkPreAgendarApenasConcluido.TabIndex + 1;
    this.txtHorarioCheckin.Tipo = DVJPetControles.textBoxTipo.Hora;
    this.txtHorarioCheckin.Leave += new 
    System.EventHandler(this.txtHorarioCheckin_Leave);

    flpPetshop.Controls.Add(this.txtHorarioCheckin);
```

Logo depois tento colocar ele pra baixo:

```
    this.txtHorarioCheckin.Top += 200;
```

Fui acompanhando pelo Debug e percebi que mesmo alterando o top dele, ele mantém um valor fixo no top.

Já tentei da seguinte maneira também:

```
    this.txtHorarioCheckin.Location = new Point(200, 200)
```

Comment: Que controlo é o `flpPetShop`?

Comment: @GabrielHenrique Logo depois quando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira correta de reposicionar um componente é utilizando a propriedade Location, assim como você fez.

Se isto não está funcionando, você deve verificar se a propriedade Dock está diferente de None.

Outra verificação possível seria na natureza do seu componente flpPetshop. Se ele for do tipo Stack, onde ele empilha os componentes internos, então isso poderia ser o problema.